# Trigger without click?

Tags: jquery, triggers, manual

I'd like to run a scroll function:

```
$("body").scrollTo({ top: "0px", left: "2200px" }, 800);
```

...without any manual (click) trigger, so basically it should run on load. is it possible?

Comment: No need to trigger anything. The code above will scroll the body immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding .load()

```
$("body").load().scrollTo({ top: "0px", left: "2200px" }, 800);
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fcAb/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Eh? Not quite sure what you're asking. You can programatically trigger a click without the user having to physically click his mouse by calling `.trigger('click')` on the element in question.

If you just want to the scroll to occur immediately, wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`